# How do I type guard "this" inside the whole definition of a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, class, generics, types

I have an unsupported situation where I am writing a class decorator which generates a class that extends a *union* of classes.

```
class ClassA {
  member: "hello"
}

class ClassB {
  member: "world"
}

type Union = ClassA | ClassB;

export function Decorator<I extends Union>(
  Base: new (...args: any[]) => I
) {
  // typescipt currently doesn't allow extension of union of classes,
  // only intersections, even if every member of the union is a class
  // and the JS should work.
  // So this cast to an 'object' constructor is to ignore the error.
  // Only piece missing is that the Generated class is missing Union's
  // types.
  abstract class Generated extends (Base as new (
    ...args: any[]
  ) => object) {

    ... 

    exampleMethod() {
      this.member; // member is not defined in `object`, so I want to cast 'this' to `Generated & I`
    }
    ...

  }
  return Generated as any new (...args: any[]) => Generated & I;
}
```

The reason I want to do this is to work around the restriction that classes must extend `an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.` - ts(2509)

I have tried to type guard `this` in each function explicitly, by using

```
function guard(obj: any): obj is I & Generated {
  return true;
}

...
    exampleMethod() {
      if (!guard(this)) throw {};
      this.member; // works!
    }
```

And also by using [this parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters)

While both worked, they both require adding a line to each method, which can be accidentally left out and feels unnatural. I am wondering if  there's a way to do it once for the entire class.

Comment: Can you articulate *why* you need to support the class instance itself being a union?  I you just don't know what class you're decorating you could use `{member: "hello" | "world"}` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrXklW); you still run into issues with *unions of class constructors* that way, but there's no great way around that.  If you need to treat each instance as a union instead of a non-union with union properties, could you show a [mre] that motivates that need?

Comment: If you really need to have your instances be unions inside the class, then you could maybe get away with [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7o9DN), to add methods to a union of constructors... but it will still be fairly annoying to use, since TS will not allow interfaces (like the instance side of a class) to be unions.  Which brings me back to the question: what use case is this supposed to be addressing? I'd hate to spend a lot of time on what turns out to be an XY problem that has a more conventional solution.

Comment: If you reply or [edit] and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me. Good luck!